# How to track changes in form object in aurelia to activate revert button

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, aurelia

We are using Aurelia to crate a single page application where we are creating/Editing Employee details. In Edit employee form, we need to give functionality to revert local changes if any. But the trick is to disable button if there are no local changes

I tried using **computedFrom**, but its only observing the properties and not the complex object.

Here is a sample code -

```js
import {bindable, computedFrom} from 'aurelia-framework'


export class Employee {
  @bindable employee
  
  @computedFrom('employee')
  enableRevert() {
    return true;
  }
  
  revert() {
   // revert functionality goes here
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You could create a copy of the original object, iterate over its properties to see if there's something different, then enable/disable the button. Here's my real opinion: leave the revert button enabled all the time, there's no need to enable/disable this button. Keep things simple

Comment: As of now we need this functionality as a client requirement. I agree with your solution but the thing is when we should compare if anything has changed in the object?
There are lot of properties in Employee object and we really cant watch each and every property to check if the original object is changed or not..

So i was just looking for some functionality similar to "computedFrom" in aurelia which triggers that method when anything changed what it observes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**employee.html**

```
<button disabled.bind="!hasChanged()">Revert</button>
```

**employee.js**

```
attached() {
    Object.assign(this.originalEmployee, employee);
}

hasChanged() {
    // Like @Favio said, iterate over an original copy of the employee object.
    for (let p in employee) {
        if (employee[p] !== this.originalEmployee[p]) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: hasChanged will work on the first bind but whenever something changed in employee object it will not call hasChanged method again?

Comment: in the above example, hasChanged() would be dirty-checked, which means it will be called every ~100ms (approximated value, I don't know the aurelia's dirty-check interval, but you can consider as "every time")

Comment: Added parens on hasChanged in HTML.

Comment: As @Fabio says, it will be dirty checked. To avoid that, you could add a computedFrom decorator on the hasChanged method listing each employee property to be checked.

Comment: Dirty check would be bit risky in terms of the performance as after every set interval its going to check if there is changed in Employee object, where other hand Computed form is like eventing system and gets triggered whenever something changed in it. but the problem is computedFrom is only working on the properties and not on the complex object like Employee

Comment: @jeff-g : I'm approving your solution as this the best what we could do as of now with Aurelia. Thanks for your help! :)